# Building a grid using a string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, loops, logic

I've been working with a JavaScript textbook and going through some preliminary exercises. I'm self teaching myself currently.

One exercise calls to create an 8 X 8 board using "#". I did it very simply and was able to produce what the book looks like, and then I looked at the answer. I have a couple questions around the logic

```js
let board2 = " # # # #\n# # # #";
for (let n = 0; n < 4; n++) {
  console.log(board2);
}
```

The book does the following

```js
let size = 8;

let board = "";

for (let y = 0; y < size; y++) {
  for (let x = 0; x < size; x++) {
    if ((x + y) % 2 == 0) {
      board += " ";
    } else {
      board += "#";
    }
  }
  board += "\n";
}

console.log(board);
```

What I understand is that if the sum of the X and Y coordinates are even it will add a " " to the board. How do you reach this logic? Is it for every other position in the string to have a space, and then odd numbers contain a "#"?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what it's doing. The nested loops are so that it can add a newline at the end of each row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In even-numbered rows you want space in the even columns and `#` in the odd columns. Adding an even row and an even column always produces an even sum, so even columns will be when `x + y` is even.

In odd-numbered rows you want the opposite: space in the odd columns and `#` in the even columns. Adding an odd row and an odd column will produce an even sum, so odd columns will be when `x + y` is even.

So from this simple math we can see that we always want to add a space when `x + y` is even, otherwise add `#`, and it will alternate the layout in the rows.

Your method is fine when you can hard-code the grid size. The method in the book is more general -- it works with any grid size, and doesn't depend on there being an even number of rows.